# routing forms and related models

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

This a beginners question about how to set up the route and controllers for a simple management system in Laravel 4.2.

Lets say I have a 'person' model (contains 'name' and 'email'). I also have a 'books' model that belongs to 'person' (contains 'title' and 'author', 'person_id').

To create a new person, the route to the form is:

> example.com/persons/create

I would like the route for associating a new book to a person to be something like:

> example.com/persons/22/books/create

Currently my routes are set up like this:

```
Route::resource('persons', 'PersonsController');
Route::resource('books', 'BooksController');
```

My person model contains the function:

```
public function books(){
  return $this->hasMany('Book');
}
```

My book model contains the function:

```
public function persons(){
  return $this->belongsTo('Person');
}
```

Where have I gone wrong? What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers):

> To "nest" resource controllers, use "dot" notation in your route declaration

```
Route::resource('persons.books', 'BooksController');
```

To get a list of registered route paths, you can use console command `php artisan routes`